# Check uniqueness for multiple attributes in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table of the form `ID, MID,PID`. Now, for the table ID is the primary key. and I might come across inserting same combination of `MID,PID` , but I shouldn't add them. Here ID is something which needs to be generated and can't be obtained or crawled. Is there any mechanism in SQL to check for **uniqueness of the combination**.

I an thinking of generating ID with auto increment, so it being primary key can't help here,another option I am thinking is, concatenate MID and PID and then set them as primary key. Else I could check if the data exists with a select command and then do the same. But all these kind of defeats the purpose, or to say the least not elegant. Are there any other methods?

Will creating a `constraint` serve it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, adding a (composite) *uniqueness constraint* is exactly what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD UNIQUE (MID, PID)
```

Comment: @Amrith Krishna - also, look at surrogate vs natural keys.